# Third party MCAL integration issue using Vector stack

Tags: embedded, autosar

I installed the Vector SIP and linked the MCAL path using the thirdparty MCAL Integration tool. Imported the modules from SIP and configured. While generating MCU, I was seeing the issue as below:
"Tresos79001    tresos_cmd_64.bat has returned the ExitCode 1 during Validation".

Please let me know your suggestions to resolve this issue.

As I have already gave the path to MCAL using the third-party integration tool I am not expecting the tresos errors.

Comment: This error can came from wrong configuration for MCU in Davinci Configurator. Did you check the ouput for this error in "Generation Result"?

Comment: Thanks Niki, seems there are configuration errors in MCU. Issue resolved. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Remove Read only property of Tresos79001 tresos_cmd_64.bat.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the error, I faced while updating MCAL from 1.4 to 2.0, And if you generate report those errors won't match with the existing configuration.